# How wide can a postgresSQL table be before I run into issues?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

According to the limits postgres supports up to 1600 columns per table.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/limits.html

I understand that it's bad practice to have so many columns but what are the consequences of approaching this limit?

For example, will a table with 200 columns perform fine in an application? How can you tell when you're approaching too many columns for a given table?

Comment: If you need that many columns in one table, your schema is wrong and should be refactored.

Comment: A relational database like PostgreSQL, works best when you normalize your data. When doing so, it's unlikely that you will have end up with so many columns in a single table. Of me, 20 to 30 columns is already a lot. 200 would be way too much and would prove that I did something wrong. But exceptions do exist. 3NF is always my goal: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form

Answer (score 1):

The hard limit is that a table row has to fit inside a single 8kB block.

The "soft limits" you encounter with many columns are

- writing `SELECT` list becomes more and more annoying (never, ever, use `SELECT *`)
- each `UPDATE` has to write a large row version, so lots of data churn
- extracting the 603th column from a row requires skipping the previous 602 columns, which is a performance hit
- it is plain annoying if the output of `\d` is 50 pages long

Comment: I plainly confirms Laurenz Albe words... Such table having too much columns are called obese tables. I wrote a paper for Microsoft SQL Server about that problem but it is avaialable only in french... Use Google Translate to understand why.... https://blog.developpez.com/sqlpro/p10070/langage-sql-norme/base_de_donnees_et_performances_petites